# Do extended regexes support back-references?

Tags: c, regex, posix

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that extended regexes "dropped support for backreferences", so the "basic" regex mode has to be used to enable those. However, it seems that a number of implementations *do* support backreferences for extended regexes. For example, with gcc 4.6 on Ubuntu Precise, they are supported. FreeBSD implementations [seem to](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/re_format/) support them only in basic mode.

[Boost says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html) (and seems to agree with Wikipedia) that backreferences are not supported for extended regexes, but Boost::Regex adds them as an extension.

Is this just a poorly defined part of the standard which is interpreted differently by every implementation?

Comment: Wikipedia is not always the best source for reliable information. I see no reason why backreferences should not be supported in extended regex in any implementation/environment. POSIX standard does not support back-references for extended regular expressions, but I don't know any implementation that would follow this "standard".

Comment: +Ωmega apparently FreeBSD implementations do follow this. Reading the "re_format" manpage, a special "enhanced" mode was added to support backreferences in extended mode

Comment: It seems that `egrep` in FreeBSD supports them.

Comment: OpenBSD, OTOH, does seem to reserve backreferences only to BREs (Basic Regular Expressions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, it's quite clear that POSIX EREs do not support back-references.

The rationale given in the OpenGroup *Base Specifications Issue 7* for not adding back-references to EREs is given as:

> It was suggested that, in addition to interval expressions, back-references ( '\n' ) should also be added to EREs. This was rejected by the standard developers as likely to decrease consensus.

Quoted from: [Rationale: Base Definitions: Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html)

The primary reason for this limitation is to allow POSIX EREs to be converted to a deterministic finite automata (DFA), and indeed the original implementation of EREs in Unix was done as a DFA.  The use of a DFA allows guarantees to be made about the performance of the implementation.  Pattern matching with (an unbounded number of) back references is an NP-hard problem, and perhaps even an NP-complete problem.  Consensus in the POSIX standards committee could never have been reached if back-references were proposed for EREs because that would force all the companies using the original Unix implementation to change their code to a non-deterministic implementation and to drop their performance guarantees, and some of those companies had members on the committee.

It has also been noted that back-references in REs are not intuitive for either users or implementors, and indeed they've caused extreme confusion more often than now.  See for example the examples given in [RE-Interpretation: The Dark Corners](http://public.research.att.com/~gsf/testregex/re-interpretation.html#The%20Dark%20Corners)

**NOTE:** back-references in REs are not the same as references to sub-patterns in substitution text in tools such as sed.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [IEEE/Open Group standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) Extended Regular Expressions don't support Backreferences (Section 9.5.1) although several real-world implementations do.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [POSIX.1-2008 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), only Basic Regular Expressions support back-references.  [Section 9.3.6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) describes how they work in BREs.  The Extended Regular Expressions section doesn't mention them at all, and the [Grammar Lexical Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_05_01) in section 9.5.1 say that back-reference tokens only apply to BREs.